# Is there a way to display image encoded into a string longer than 100 000 characters? (Java, Spring, Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, base64, thymeleaf, bytea

So, i have a form that allows user to upload an image, which will be encoded with IOUtils.toByteArray and persisted to a database as a bytea. In a controller method i get this byte array and encode it to string:

```
@GetMapping("/{user_id}")
public String view(@PathVariable("user_id") Long user_id, Model model) {
    User user = userService.getById(user_id);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    byte[] profilePictureBytes = user.getProfilePicture();

    if (profilePictureBytes != null) {
        String encodedImage = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(profilePictureBytes);
        model.addAttribute("encodedImage", encodedImage);
    }
    return "user-page";
}
```

On a user-page html file i try to decode it like this:

```
<img th:attr="src=${'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + encodedImage}" alt="Profile Picture">
```

This solution works for smaller images but throws an exception when the encoded image exceeds 100 000 characters:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + encodedImage" (template: "user-page" - line 27, col 6)

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1078E: Concatenated string is too long, exceeding the threshold of '100 000' characters
```

Is there a way to circumvent this limit or should i change the whole logic of the program instead? Thank you.

Comment: Please include the exception stacktrace or log in the question.

Comment: Included the exceptions, might include the whole stacktrace, but i think it is not necessary.

Comment: I'm afraid that is hardcoded limit in `spring`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/73d30dd875affac7dc69232bf4c6b183e0801c26/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/OpPlus.java#L156, I believe, passing the final value via model attributes should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is tricky! TY, @Andrey(, again;) for exactly pointing the "issue". I'm not sure, whether it is worth to open a spring issue/request/enhancement for this.

But:

- (as it looks, github search) this check only applies on the (Spring EL) "string concatenation"
- to "circumvent", we can ... use thymeleaf features:

  - Couldn't make it work with "inline expressions", yet... (seems not to work with "attrs")
  - but with `th:attrappend` !! ;) (instead of Spring EL string concat;)

Resulting template:

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64," th:attrappend="src=${encodedImage}" alt="Profile Picture">
```

(Test) Controller used:

```java
@Controller
class DemoController {

    final String encodedImage;

    public DemoController(
            @Value("classpath:/bigImage.jpg") /* source: https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/main/bigimage/bigImage.jpg */
            Resource bigPic) throws IOException {
        this.encodedImage = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bigPic.getContentAsByteArray());
    }

    @ModelAttribute("encodedImage")
    public String encodedImage() throws IOException {
        return encodedImage;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

#### Generally

"These type of things" belong "into the caches of load balancers"! (..and not into the "memory" (`byte[], Base64`...) of your "back ends" :)

#### Advanced

It'd be nice to "attach" these (kind of) things (to html/http response) similar to https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html, like:

- template:

  ```html
  <img src="sample.png" th:src="|cid:${imageResourceName}|" />
  ```
- but unfortunately we can't (I didn't find it yet, as in `MimeMessage` `addInline`)

#### Another (Simple) Workaround

```java
@ModelAttribute("encodedImageAttr")
public String encodedImageAttr() throws IOException {
    return String.format("data:image/jpeg;base64,%s", encodedImage);;
}
```

...serve the complete attribute value instead of the "base64 part".

Template then looks like:

```html
<img src="" th:attr="src=${encodedImageAttr}" alt="Profile Picture">
```

(I also tried with template SpEL `th:attr="src=${#T(java.lang.String).format('data:image/jpeg;base64,%s', encodedImageAttr)}"`, but failed due to:

```text
...
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Instantiation of new objects and access to static classes or parameters is forbidden in this context (template: "test" - line 6, col 17)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Instantiation of new objects and access to static classes or parameters is forbidden in this context (template: "test" - line 6, col 17)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.obtainComputedSpelExpression(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:309)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:182)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
...
```

)